# How can I use emmet's lorem ipsum functionality in latex files for visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I want emmet to work for my latex files as well.

I have been trying to follow [the documentation here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) but it is  not exactly clear to me what exactly the language identifiers are and where they are defined.
[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) they display a list of the language identifiers but still I do not know what is expected on either side of the key-value pair.

This is what I have tried:
In my settings.json file, I added the following

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "latex": "latex"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "latex": "html"
}
```

The second language is the mode you want Emmet to be and has to be an already supported language id.